# Rsync and Windows 7

Tags: ubuntu, windows, rsync, backup

Can someone give me any tips on setting up some sort of Rsync server/client on Windows 7 to run rsync between both my web hosting server, and a backup server that I have running Ubuntu? I've tried setting it up with [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CvwdkZLNtnA) tutorial using copssh, and cwrsync.

Following the tutorial ran me into all sorts of troubles, including not being able to get cwrsync to run (it installs properly, but never starts up), and copssh not generating the keys at all. The guy was running Windows Server 2003 though.so I'm guessing that the problems could just be because I'm running Windows 7.

I've been trying to set it up with my Windows machine being the rsync server, and then Ubuntu and my webhosting VPS as the clients, but I realize it may be easier (and make more sense) to just setup the rsync server on Ubuntu, and then an rsync client on Windows 7?

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm thinking of using [this](http://www.gaztronics.net/rsync.php) guide.
It seems a bit outdated though.

Answer (score 0):

See my article on using [Setting up BackupPC on Windows](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/setting-up-backuppc-on-windows/).  Setup for cwrsync as a server should be identical other than the path to `rsync.exe`.  I am planning on switching to the cwrsync version of `rsync` as I installed it for use by Unison.

To use `rsync` as a client you should add its directory to your path.  Defining a HOME directory may also be required, and definitely makes use of the included `ssh` client much easier.

cpossh is only needed if you want to configure an ssh server.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look into that. Doesn't look too hard. (I wanted to try to get this setup tonight, but I'm ironically having hardware issues now! Heh.)